# Nativescript loading custom component

Tags: nativescript

I try to load custom componets(View) when tabs are loaded.
my directory structure is:
this is my tablist.html page:

```
       var myComponentInstance = builder.load({
            path: "pages/product/product.component",
            name: "product_lists"
        });
```

this.tabviewitems.push({ "title": this.subCategories[index], "view": myComponentInstance });

my view is not getting loaded.
view._inheritProperties is not a function in nativescript
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are trying to generate a TabView programmatically? I suggest putting the page instance inside the `builder.load` function:

```
var myComponentInstance = builder.load({
    path: "pages/product/product.component",
    name: "product_lists",
    page: myPage
});
```

Then when generate the TabView UI:

```
let itemsArray = [];
let tabView = new TabView();
tabView.selectedColor = new Color("#000000");
for (let i in someArray) {
    let tabEntry = {
        title: someArray[i],
        view: customView 
    };
    items.push(tabEntry);
}
tabView.items = items;
```

Comment: yeahhh I am trying to load Tabview dynamically.how to I get 'myPage', Actually I am trying to load 'product_lists.html' page.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong. I understand that you are in one page, and you are generating TabView dynamically inside that page. Then you want to load another page(which is `product_lists` page) into a TabView item. Could you post some more `XML` and js file so that I can see better?

Comment: yeah .. you are correct. I want my productList.html page inside this tabview.  My tablistComponet.ts file is :for (var index = 0; index < this.subCategories.length; index++) { var innerStackLayout = new StackLayout();var myComponentInstance = builder.load({ path: "pages/product/product.component",name: "product_lists.html",               
 })innerStackLayout.addChild(myComponentInstance); this.tabviewitems.push({ "title": this.subCategories[index], "view": innerStackLayout });} If I do like this I am getting error of view._inheritProperties is not a function in nativescript .Thank you Sir

Comment: 1. you don't need to include the `.html`, just `name: "product_lists"` 2. Remove the double quote on `title` and `view` when you push to tabViewItems 3. I don't see you assign the `this.tabviewitems` to any TabView instance

Comment: still getting same error. view._inheritProperties is not a function in nativescript

Answer (score 0):

In case your are using NativeScript Anguler2 template to create your project, you could load custom component in the TabView without using `builder.loade`. You could review the below attached example how you could create such a custom component and to add it in `TabView`.

product.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";


@Component({
    selector: 'product-component',
    template: `
        <StackLayout>
            <Label [text]="data" class="name"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class ProductComponent {
    @Input() data: string;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<GridLayout>
    <TabView #tabView>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab1'}">
            <product-component data="Sample title" ></product-component>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab2'}">
            <Label text="This is Label in Tab 2"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </TabView>
</GridLayout>
```

main.ts

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import {ProductComponent} from "./product.component"

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ProductComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [NativeScriptModule],
})
class AppComponentModule {}

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponentModule);
```

The important part is to add your custom component in the declarations in your `main.ts` file. To share data between different components you could use `@Input()` in your project. You could read more about it [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/)